# How to update child widget (loading indicator) with current value of PageController?

Tags: dart, flutter, loading

I would like to animate `LinearProgressIndicator` only if the current value of `PageController` (or `PageView`) is the same as its index in `Row`.

As you can see in the screenshot I have a `PageView` with a row of `LinearProgressIndicator`s. `PageView` is controlled with its own `PageController` and the pages are switched when `AnimationController` reaches its end.

[image: iPhone screenshot with the current outcome]

I would like to achieve effect similar to [this idea](https://dribbble.com/shots/5835036-Movie-APP) i.e. only the `LoadingIndicator` for current page should be animated.

## Code

Below you may find the code of the top widget i.e. `PageView` with bottom row of `LoadingIndicator`s.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewWithLoadingIndicators extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> imageUrls;
  final List<Widget> images;
  final Duration totalDuration;
  final Duration transitionDuration;
  final Curve animationCurve;

  const PageViewWithLoadingIndicators(
      {Key key,
      this.imageUrls,
      this.images,
      this.totalDuration = const Duration(seconds: 10),
      this.transitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      this.animationCurve = Curves.easeInOut})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  PageViewWithLoadingIndicatorsState createState() => PageViewWithLoadingIndicatorsState();
}

class PageViewWithLoadingIndicatorsState extends State<PageViewWithLoadingIndicators>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> loadingBarAnimation;
  AnimationController controller;
  PageController pageController;
  int count;
  int index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assert(widget.imageUrls.isNotEmpty || widget.images.isNotEmpty);

    count = widget.imageUrls.length;
    index = 0;
    controller = AnimationController(duration: widget.totalDuration ~/ count, vsync: this);
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

    loadingBarAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.reset();
          setState(() {
            index++;
          });
          if (index == count) {
            setState(() {
              index = 0;
            });
          }
          pageController.animateToPage(index,
              curve: widget.animationCurve, duration: widget.transitionDuration);
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller.forward();
        }
      });

    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: PageView(
            children: widget.images != null
                ? widget.images
                : widget.imageUrls
                    .map<Widget>((f) => Image.network(
                          f,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ))
                    .toList(),
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: PageLoader(animation: loadingBarAnimation, count: count),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PageLoader extends AnimatedWidget {
  final int count;

  PageLoader({Key key, @required this.count, Animation<double> animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = listenable;

    return Row(
        children: List.generate(
      count,
      (index) => SmallLoadingBar(animation, index),
    ));
  }
}

class SmallLoadingBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final Animation<double> value;

  SmallLoadingBar(this.value, this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
          height: 5,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white24),
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white70),
              value: value.value)),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use it simply:

```dart
  final List<String> images = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/F8PBP7P.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/DtWaRhg.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/GsRLPXM.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/BMnhHaH.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/qXvgwpw.jpg',
  ];

PageViewWithLoadingIndicators(imageUrls: images)
```

What is the best approach here? Using `InheritedWidget` or Stream to check the current page index inside LoadingIndicator container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to animate LinearProgressIndicator only if the current
>   value of PageController (or PageView) is the same as its index in Row.

That is simple to do with your current code. All you have to do is to pass along the index that you update in the animation listener. First of all you can simplify your animation listener code a bit:

```
setState(() {
    index++;
    if (index == count) {
       index = 0;
    }
});
```

Then pass the index value through the widget hierarchy to the LinearProgressIndicator where you will use it:

```
// in PageViewWithLoadingIndicatorsState's build() method
child: PageLoader(animation: loadingBarAnimation, count: count, current: index),
```

In SmallLoadingBar you can then use the passed value to animate only the current loading indicator:

```
class SmallLoadingBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final Animation<double> value;
  final int current;

  SmallLoadingBar(this.value, this.index, this.current);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
          height: 5,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white24),
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white70),
              value: _calculateState(index, current))),
    );
  }

  double _calculateState(int index, int current) {
    // this is the page at which we are so it needs to be animated
    if (index == current) {
      return value.value;
    } else if (index < current) {
      // this is behind the current indicator so was already animated
      return 1;
    } else {
      // this is after the current indicator so it wasn't yet animated
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, to really make this work you would need to tie the animation that you pass to the indicators to the actual image loading times. How to do this depends on how you plan to handle the loading of the images.